# Going from dplyr to base: create a data frame of the first and last index for each level of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Asking how to go from `dplyr` to `base` may be a weird ask, especially since I love the `tidyverse`, but I think because I learned the `tidyverse` first, my grasp of base is far from masterful, and I need a `base` solution because the package I'm helping to develop doesn't want any `tidyverse` dependencies

**Data** (there are many more columns, but abbreviated for reprex sake):

```
sample.df <- tibble(batch = rep(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)))
```

**Desire base equivalent of:**

```
sample.df %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(batch) %>%
  summarize(idx_b = min(rowid),
            idx_e = max(rowid))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   batch [3]
  batch idx_b idx_e
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     1     4
2     2     5     9
3     3    10    15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a sequence column in the data, use `aggregate` to get the `range` or `min/max` and convert the matrix column to regular data.frame column with `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(rowid ~ batch,
   transform(sample.df, rowid = seq_len(nrow(sample.df))), 
      FUN = function(x) c(b = min(x), e = max(x))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option using `unique` + `ave`

```
unique(
  transform(
    sample.df,
    idx_b = ave(1:nrow(sample.df), batch, FUN = min),
    idx_c = ave(1:nrow(sample.df), batch, FUN = max)
  )
)
```

gives

```
   batch idx_b idx_c
1      1     1     4
5      2     5     9
10     3    10    15
```